# ¿Cómo desencripto la información de mi base de datos?

Tags: mysql, seguridad

Estoy intentando realizar una encriptación de mi base de datos con `AES_ENCRYPT`:

```
INSERT INTO prueba (prueba.no_encriptado, prueba.encriptado_prueba) 
VALUES ('Esto no se encripta', AES_ENCRYPT('Esto sí se encripta', 'db89bb5ceab87f9c0fcc2ab36c189c2c'));
```

Pero cuando lo llamo con `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(prueba.encriptado_prueba, 'db89bb5ceab87f9c0fcc2ab36c189c2c') AS texto FROM prueba;` siempre me devuelve NULL. Estoy usando la versión de **XAMPP** que tiene PHP 8, no sé si la versión tenga algo que ver.

Adicional (o por el contrario) de la respuesta, quisiera saber si hay una alternativa más segura y actual para encriptar con MySQL.

A parte de eso, me gustaría preguntar qué tan útil sería encriptar casi todas las columnas de una tabla con estos métodos.

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

También adjunto el código de la base de datos por si hay alguna configuración que no me permite encriptar:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generaciÃ³n: 31-08-2021 a las 03:34:59
-- VersiÃ³n del servidor: 10.4.20-MariaDB
-- VersiÃ³n de PHP: 8.0.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `encriptacion`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `prueba`
--

CREATE TABLE `prueba` (
  `id_prueba` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_encriptado` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `encriptado_prueba` longtext COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `prueba`
--

INSERT INTO `prueba` (`id_prueba`, `no_encriptado`, `encriptado_prueba`) VALUES
(1, 'Esto no se ecnripta', '?i??5???0h?1^\nmZr??/LA?L??B9??'),
(2, 'Esto no se encripta', '?i??5???0h?1^\nmZr??/LA?L??B9??');

--
-- Ãndices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `prueba`
--
ALTER TABLE `prueba`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_prueba`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `prueba`
--
ALTER TABLE `prueba`
  MODIFY `id_prueba` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: A parte de eso, me gustaría preguntar qué tan útil sería encriptar casi todas las columnas de una tabla con estos métodos.: ninguna.. y menos si es simetrica y se puede desencriptar.. no tiene ningun sentido...

Comment: ademas, como vas a hacer un simple select si todo esta encriptado? lo unico que deberia estar encriptado son las password.. y con un metodo que no permita desencriptarlas.. este que estas usando, no.....

Comment: Pues, la idea me surgió porque en un foro de seguridad, daban esa propuesta como extra de seguridad, ya que sin la llave, igual no pueden acceder a los datos. Pero por simple curiosidad, ¿se te ocurre algo por lo cuál siempre me traiga NULL?

Comment: no ni idea de tu error... y esa gente IMHO no mucho de seguridad.. si ya entraron a tu base de datos, se llevan los datos, se toman todo el tiempo del mundo en desencriptarlos, y lo que hiciste no sirvio para nada... no veo el punto en encriptar nada salvo los passwords.... pero tu pregunta, es valida sobre porque no funciona eso....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre qué tan útil, eso es una opinión y depende. Hay datos como números de tarjetas de crédito, Identificaciones personales y esas cosas, Personal Identifiable Information, que debería estar cifrada en reposo y en tránsito para que a nadie se le tuerza el corazón y se comience a robar cosas.
Para todo lo demás, cifrar columnas es caro porque es tiempo adicional a la consulta que gastas cifrando y descifrando. Cada Motor de BD tiene su aproximación a este problema.

Para guardar contraseñas, uno sólo guarda un salted hash y luego, cuando alguien se autentica, compara lo que recibe, volviendo a generar el salted hash, contra lo guardado. Uno no compara contraseñas texto en claro nunca jamás en la vida, *never*, EVER.

Sobre el código que no te funciona, pasa que AES_ENCRYPT genera un binary text, así que necesitas un VARBINARY, no un longtext. El problema no es de longitud esperada, sino de formato.

```
CREATE TABLE `prueba` (
  `id_prueba` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_encriptado` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `encriptado_prueba` varbinary(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO prueba (id_prueba, no_encriptado, encriptado_prueba) VALUES (11, 'pepito', AES_ENCRYPT('algo encriptado', UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')));
```

Así mismo, recomiendan una forma saludable de entregar la llave de cifrado en la [documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt). Ahí también indica que, si estás configurando algo mal, esas funciones van a retornar NULL.

Para consultar tu dato cifrado, pues

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(encriptado_prueba, UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')) AS CHAR(60)) AS texto FROM prueba;
```

haces un cast del varbinary a una cadena de char y ya está.